# sprintf length specifier in PHP

Tags: php, printf

Is there any benefit to include the [*length specifier*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) in a format string for `sprintf` or `printf` even though it's not mentioned [in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

- `h` - The argument is interpreted as a short int or unsigned short int (only applies to integer specifiers: `i`, `d`, `o`, `u`, `x` and `X`).
- `l` - The argument is interpreted as a long int or unsigned long int for integer specifiers (`i`, `d`, `o`, `u`, `x` and `X`), and as a wide character or wide character string for specifiers `c` and `s`.
- `L` - The argument is interpreted as a long double (only applies to floating point specifiers: `e`, `E`, `f`, `g` and `G`).

Or is it better to leave it out? I guess what I'm trying to figure out is why php decided to leave it out.

Consider the following code, which comes from phpriot.com:

```
$a = 0.5;
$b = 0.1;
$c = 16;

echo sprintf('%01.2lf %.1lf 0x%x', $a, $b, $c); # 0.50 0.1 0x10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP there are no differentiation between numbers except for [Integers](http://us.php.net/integer) and [Floats](http://us.php.net/float). Depending on system architecture, 32 or 64-bit, the Integer type is a int or int64. You can use strings and BCMath to imitate larger numbers, but they'll always be stored in strings.

So in PHP there's no purpose to have a length specifier to change the type of the number. Either it's a float, or it's not.

Answer (score 4):

It's not needed. PHP doesn't have short ints, ints, long ints, etc. It has only [`ints`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).